# Google Chrome Plugin accessing downloads

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to access a user's downloads with a google chrome plugin? I've looked at [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) documentation, but I'm still confused as to how it works

Comment: `chrome.downloads.*` is the API you're looking for: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads